# Why I can't restart nodemon in a typescript project?

Tags: powershell, nodemon

[image: Terminal image]

Terminal input is not working while am running nodemon after update. I need the 'rs' option in the terminal for restarting the project in some cases.
I searched in the google and didn't find any helpful answers!

Comment: It says to restart type rs.

Comment: but the terminal input is not working

Comment: js script my be in an infinite loop.  To make sure everything is working properly try a simple js script.

Comment: Just to rule out an obvious problem: Did you press Enter after typing "rs" (while `nodemon` is running?